# PTIJ: Seeking info about Chazzan R. Neves

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

This year's *JAK Rettelswen* mentions a recording of Kiddush Yaknha"z (Jag 'n Has) sung by Chazzan R. Neves. Does anoyone know about Mr. Neves and if he did any other recordings ?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Am I the only person who's completely lost?

Comment: יקנה"ז is a pun in Middle High German/Old Western Yiddish with "hunting the hare/rabbit." R. Neves sounds like *arneves*, or *arnevet* in those dialects which don't distinguish תּ and תֿ

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Presumably in those dialects which do distinguish תּ and תֿ it should sound like *ʾarnebheth*, but let's not ruin a good joke...

Comment: @heshy It's an old, old joke https://blog.nli.org.il/en/hare_hunting_haggadah/ http://huc.edu/research/libraries/blog/2012/04/04/hare-hunting-in-haggadah

Answer (score 3):

No this debut album proved quite the flop, people felt he just kept rabbiting on!

Meanwhile the whole יקנה"ז thing has met mass protest by animal-rights protestors. Even leading goyim have been seen in a [negative light](https://www.sefaria.org/Nedarim.65a.2?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi).

Comment: I presume listening to it must be a hare-raising experience...

Comment: Yeah he wasn't too hoppy about it!

Comment: The whole experience gave him many a grey hare.

Answer (score 1):

I had an entire collection of wax records by the chazzan.

Unfortunately the records were stored in a cabinet whose doors were not locked, and when we moved from Ansbach to Dusseldorf, the removalists lifted the cabinet out of the truck with the door facing the road and all the records fell out and were smashed to smithereens.

Answer (score 1):

Last I heard, he's given up on the music business. He's settled down and [married](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Megillah.9b.3?lang=bi) [a giant](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sotah.34b.10?lang=bi).